# How to replace non-printable unicode characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, non-printing-characters

I've already wasted a good amount of time dealing with strings (generated by some other source) and I found out that the problem was that the strings have non-printable characters. Today I am dealing with javascript. Does anyone know how to replace non-printable unicode characters in javascript?

I found something similar here:

[How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java)

> `my_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");`

and here:

[Non-ascii characters added form input only with Safari Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747271/non-ascii-characters-added-form-input-only-with-safari-browser)

> `filename.replace(/[^a-z0-9\.]+/gi, "");`

The last option replaces all the characters that are not in the brackets. This is something that has always comes to bite me in my rear end no matter what language I'm working on and I'm tired of trying to figure out what characters are messing up my code. For this reason I want to be able to replace all those invisible characters for something visible so that I can later remove them completely.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Based on what `\p{C}` is in java ([from XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/2b652889fc14524d20f85604f291f725347f8033/src/addons/unicode-categories.js#L26-L31)):

```
var re = /[\0-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\xAD\u0378\u0379\u037F-\u0383\u038B\u038D\u03A2\u0528-\u0530\u0557\u0558\u0560\u0588\u058B-\u058E\u0590\u05C8-\u05CF\u05EB-\u05EF\u05F5-\u0605\u061C\u061D\u06DD\u070E\u070F\u074B\u074C\u07B2-\u07BF\u07FB-\u07FF\u082E\u082F\u083F\u085C\u085D\u085F-\u089F\u08A1\u08AD-\u08E3\u08FF\u0978\u0980\u0984\u098D\u098E\u0991\u0992\u09A9\u09B1\u09B3-\u09B5\u09BA\u09BB\u09C5\u09C6\u09C9\u09CA\u09CF-\u09D6\u09D8-\u09DB\u09DE\u09E4\u09E5\u09FC-\u0A00\u0A04\u0A0B-\u0A0E\u0A11\u0A12\u0A29\u0A31\u0A34\u0A37\u0A3A\u0A3B\u0A3D\u0A43-\u0A46\u0A49\u0A4A\u0A4E-\u0A50\u0A52-\u0A58\u0A5D\u0A5F-\u0A65\u0A76-\u0A80\u0A84\u0A8E\u0A92\u0AA9\u0AB1\u0AB4\u0ABA\u0ABB\u0AC6\u0ACA\u0ACE\u0ACF\u0AD1-\u0ADF\u0AE4\u0AE5\u0AF2-\u0B00\u0B04\u0B0D\u0B0E\u0B11\u0B12\u0B29\u0B31\u0B34\u0B3A\u0B3B\u0B45\u0B46\u0B49\u0B4A\u0B4E-\u0B55\u0B58-\u0B5B\u0B5E\u0B64\u0B65\u0B78-\u0B81\u0B84\u0B8B-\u0B8D\u0B91\u0B96-\u0B98\u0B9B\u0B9D\u0BA0-\u0BA2\u0BA5-\u0BA7\u0BAB-\u0BAD\u0BBA-\u0BBD\u0BC3-\u0BC5\u0BC9\u0BCE\u0BCF\u0BD1-\u0BD6\u0BD8-\u0BE5\u0BFB-\u0C00\u0C04\u0C0D\u0C11\u0C29\u0C34\u0C3A-\u0C3C\u0C45\u0C49\u0C4E-\u0C54\u0C57\u0C5A-\u0C5F\u0C64\u0C65\u0C70-\u0C77\u0C80\u0C81\u0C84\u0C8D\u0C91\u0CA9\u0CB4\u0CBA\u0CBB\u0CC5\u0CC9\u0CCE-\u0CD4\u0CD7-\u0CDD\u0CDF\u0CE4\u0CE5\u0CF0\u0CF3-\u0D01\u0D04\u0D0D\u0D11\u0D3B\u0D3C\u0D45\u0D49\u0D4F-\u0D56\u0D58-\u0D5F\u0D64\u0D65\u0D76-\u0D78\u0D80\u0D81\u0D84\u0D97-\u0D99\u0DB2\u0DBC\u0DBE\u0DBF\u0DC7-\u0DC9\u0DCB-\u0DCE\u0DD5\u0DD7\u0DE0-\u0DF1\u0DF5-\u0E00\u0E3B-\u0E3E\u0E5C-\u0E80\u0E83\u0E85\u0E86\u0E89\u0E8B\u0E8C\u0E8E-\u0E93\u0E98\u0EA0\u0EA4\u0EA6\u0EA8\u0EA9\u0EAC\u0EBA\u0EBE\u0EBF\u0EC5\u0EC7\u0ECE\u0ECF\u0EDA\u0EDB\u0EE0-\u0EFF\u0F48\u0F6D-\u0F70\u0F98\u0FBD\u0FCD\u0FDB-\u0FFF\u10C6\u10C8-\u10CC\u10CE\u10CF\u1249\u124E\u124F\u1257\u1259\u125E\u125F\u1289\u128E\u128F\u12B1\u12B6\u12B7\u12BF\u12C1\u12C6\u12C7\u12D7\u1311\u1316\u1317\u135B\u135C\u137D-\u137F\u139A-\u139F\u13F5-\u13FF\u169D-\u169F\u16F1-\u16FF\u170D\u1715-\u171F\u1737-\u173F\u1754-\u175F\u176D\u1771\u1774-\u177F\u17DE\u17DF\u17EA-\u17EF\u17FA-\u17FF\u180F\u181A-\u181F\u1878-\u187F\u18AB-\u18AF\u18F6-\u18FF\u191D-\u191F\u192C-\u192F\u193C-\u193F\u1941-\u1943\u196E\u196F\u1975-\u197F\u19AC-\u19AF\u19CA-\u19CF\u19DB-\u19DD\u1A1C\u1A1D\u1A5F\u1A7D\u1A7E\u1A8A-\u1A8F\u1A9A-\u1A9F\u1AAE-\u1AFF\u1B4C-\u1B4F\u1B7D-\u1B7F\u1BF4-\u1BFB\u1C38-\u1C3A\u1C4A-\u1C4C\u1C80-\u1CBF\u1CC8-\u1CCF\u1CF7-\u1CFF\u1DE7-\u1DFB\u1F16\u1F17\u1F1E\u1F1F\u1F46\u1F47\u1F4E\u1F4F\u1F58\u1F5A\u1F5C\u1F5E\u1F7E\u1F7F\u1FB5\u1FC5\u1FD4\u1FD5\u1FDC\u1FF0\u1FF1\u1FF5\u1FFF\u200B-\u200F\u202A-\u202E\u2060-\u206F\u2072\u2073\u208F\u209D-\u209F\u20BB-\u20CF\u20F1-\u20FF\u218A-\u218F\u23F4-\u23FF\u2427-\u243F\u244B-\u245F\u2700\u2B4D-\u2B4F\u2B5A-\u2BFF\u2C2F\u2C5F\u2CF4-\u2CF8\u2D26\u2D28-\u2D2C\u2D2E\u2D2F\u2D68-\u2D6E\u2D71-\u2D7E\u2D97-\u2D9F\u2DA7\u2DAF\u2DB7\u2DBF\u2DC7\u2DCF\u2DD7\u2DDF\u2E3C-\u2E7F\u2E9A\u2EF4-\u2EFF\u2FD6-\u2FEF\u2FFC-\u2FFF\u3040\u3097\u3098\u3100-\u3104\u312E-\u3130\u318F\u31BB-\u31BF\u31E4-\u31EF\u321F\u32FF\u4DB6-\u4DBF\u9FCD-\u9FFF\uA48D-\uA48F\uA4C7-\uA4CF\uA62C-\uA63F\uA698-\uA69E\uA6F8-\uA6FF\uA78F\uA794-\uA79F\uA7AB-\uA7F7\uA82C-\uA82F\uA83A-\uA83F\uA878-\uA87F\uA8C5-\uA8CD\uA8DA-\uA8DF\uA8FC-\uA8FF\uA954-\uA95E\uA97D-\uA97F\uA9CE\uA9DA-\uA9DD\uA9E0-\uA9FF\uAA37-\uAA3F\uAA4E\uAA4F\uAA5A\uAA5B\uAA7C-\uAA7F\uAAC3-\uAADA\uAAF7-\uAB00\uAB07\uAB08\uAB0F\uAB10\uAB17-\uAB1F\uAB27\uAB2F-\uABBF\uABEE\uABEF\uABFA-\uABFF\uD7A4-\uD7AF\uD7C7-\uD7CA\uD7FC-\uF8FF\uFA6E\uFA6F\uFADA-\uFAFF\uFB07-\uFB12\uFB18-\uFB1C\uFB37\uFB3D\uFB3F\uFB42\uFB45\uFBC2-\uFBD2\uFD40-\uFD4F\uFD90\uFD91\uFDC8-\uFDEF\uFDFE\uFDFF\uFE1A-\uFE1F\uFE27-\uFE2F\uFE53\uFE67\uFE6C-\uFE6F\uFE75\uFEFD-\uFF00\uFFBF-\uFFC1\uFFC8\uFFC9\uFFD0\uFFD1\uFFD8\uFFD9\uFFDD-\uFFDF\uFFE7\uFFEF-\uFFFB\uFFFE\uFFFF]/g;
filename.replace(re, "");
```

You could alternatively just use the [library](https://github.com/slevithan/XRegExp)

Comment: Thank you for this. In case any one wonders: it matches new lines as well; in our case we removed it.

Comment: what are these values called.. what do the letters represent?

Comment: which one of these matches newline?

Comment: `\uD7FC-\uF8FF` - this range includes surrogates (`\uD800 - \uDFFF`). Removing surrogates seems strange - since JS uses those as part of its UTF-16 encoding for strings. Removing them effectively means loosing 16 planes of characters - most of which are quite printable. TLDR - I think this question requires a basic explanation along with code.

Comment: @Olga Well, firstly 10 planes are completely unassigned and 3 are custom use so that's only 2 planes of characters being lost, not most. What is in those 2 planes then? Back when this answer was made, non-bmp characters were not printable in normal use. Even now it's only emojis that work and they are used with ascii syntax and replaced with images...

Comment: @Esailija oh I see what you mean, I did know there were gaps - I didn't think they were so big =). I would leave surrogates though. But I guess that really depends on application.

Comment: @Philip the part `\0-\x1F` matches "control characters" which includes \xA aka control-J aka newline.

Comment: Solution is good, but has one issue - line breaks are also removed

Comment: Emojis like "" will be matched by this regexp. The linked library however seems to be handling such cases.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Unicode category matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```
function stripNonPrintableAndNormalize(text, stripSurrogatesAndFormats) {
    // strip control chars. optionally, keep surrogates and formats
    if(stripSurrogatesAndFormats) {
      text = text.replace(/\p{C}/gu, '');
    } else {
      text = text.replace(/\p{Cc}/gu, '');
      text = text.replace(/\p{Co}/gu, '');
      text = text.replace(/\p{Cn}/gu, '');
    }

    // other common tasks are to normalize newlines and other whitespace

    // normalize newline
    text = text.replace(/\n\r/g, '\n');
    text = text.replace(/\p{Zl}/gu, '\n');
    text = text.replace(/\p{Zp}/gu, '\n');

    // normalize space
    text = text.replace(/\p{Zs}/gu, ' ');

    return text;
}
```

The various Unicode class identifiers (e.g. `Zl` for line separator) are defined at https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table as also shown below:

| Abbr | Long | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lu | Uppercase_Letter | an uppercase letter |
| Ll | Lowercase_Letter | a lowercase letter |
| Lt | Titlecase_Letter | a digraphic character, with first part uppercase |
| LC | Cased_Letter | Lu | Ll | Lt |
| Lm | Modifier_Letter | a modifier letter |
| Lo | Other_Letter | other letters, including syllables and ideographs |
| L | Letter | Lu | Ll | Lt | Lm | Lo |
| Mn | Nonspacing_Mark | a nonspacing combining mark (zero advance width) |
| Mc | Spacing_Mark | a spacing combining mark (positive advance width) |
| Me | Enclosing_Mark | an enclosing combining mark |
| M | Mark | Mn | Mc | Me |
| Nd | Decimal_Number | a decimal digit |
| Nl | Letter_Number | a letterlike numeric character |
| No | Other_Number | a numeric character of other type |
| N | Number | Nd | Nl | No |
| Pc | Connector_Punctuation | a connecting punctuation mark, like a tie |
| Pd | Dash_Punctuation | a dash or hyphen punctuation mark |
| Ps | Open_Punctuation | an opening punctuation mark (of a pair) |
| Pe | Close_Punctuation | a closing punctuation mark (of a pair) |
| Pi | Initial_Punctuation | an initial quotation mark |
| Pf | Final_Punctuation | a final quotation mark |
| Po | Other_Punctuation | a punctuation mark of other type |
| P | Punctuation | Pc | Pd | Ps | Pe | Pi | Pf | Po |
| Sm | Math_Symbol | a symbol of mathematical use |
| Sc | Currency_Symbol | a currency sign |
| Sk | Modifier_Symbol | a non-letterlike modifier symbol |
| So | Other_Symbol | a symbol of other type |
| S | Symbol | Sm | Sc | Sk | So |
| Zs | Space_Separator | a space character (of various non-zero widths) |
| Zl | Line_Separator | U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR only |
| Zp | Paragraph_Separator | U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR only |
| Z | Separator | Zs | Zl | Zp |
| Cc | Control | a C0 or C1 control code |
| Cf | Format | a format control character |
| Cs | Surrogate | a surrogate code point |
| Co | Private_Use | a private-use character |
| Cn | Unassigned | a reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter |
| C | Other | Cc | Cf | Cs | Co | Cn |

Comment: This does not work with emojis like ❤️‍ (combined ❤️ + )

Comment: @Sergii how so? running `stripNonPrintableAndNormalize("combined ❤️ + ")` returns the given string-- just as expected, since all chars are printable.

Comment: not really `stripNonPrintableAndNormalize('❤️')` returns `'❤️'`, `stripNonPrintableAndNormalize('')` returns `''`, but `stripNonPrintableAndNormalize('❤️‍')` returns `'❤️'`

Comment: @Sergii Oh I see, thanks. I added a stripSurrogatesAndFormats option which if left off will not strip surrogates or format control chars.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice seems to dictate that you specify what you WILL accept (the white-list approach), rather than trying to filter out what you WON'T accept (the black-list approach).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271477/javascript-regex-to-specify-what-is-allowed-rather-than-what-is-not) is a similar question, although the answers are not comprehensive.

Comment: I thought that maybe there was a simple way of changing nonprintable characters but it seems that there are just way too many of them. For this reason I decided to use `strVar.replace(/[^\040-\176\200-\377]/gi, "")` to replace anything that is not one of the ascii keys I specified. So yeah, here I'm telling what I will accept.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. Most people run black lists. Just as long as you know they're not as watertight :)

Comment: Yes, but simply removing unwanted characters may not be enough. Sometimes you'll rather want to replace some character by some other (e.g. curly quotes...).