# Number is different than itself (trimming strange characters)

Tags: javascript

I've copied the first number from the windows calculator, and typed the second one. In Chrome console I get:

```
"‭65033‬" == "65033"
//false

65033‬ == 65033
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

It seems there is an unknown character at the beginning and end of it.

1) Is there a way to trim all "strange" characters without knowing them a priori?

2) Why does the windows calculator puts such chars in the number?

**Edit:** Was not explicit in the question, but any chars with valid information, such as ã,ü,ç,¢,£ would also be valid. What I don't want is characters that do not carry any information for the human reader.

Comment: 1) Sure, you can strip out anything that isn't a digit. 2) Who knows.

Comment: It seems that there's some invisible characters `\xe2\x80\xac` after the first 65033.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, for the case of number input that would solve. I guess I didn't explicit that, but I would expect other characters as well (it's for a "search anything" function).

Comment: "What I don't want is characters that do not carry any information for the human reader". How do you define this?

Comment: I just copied a value from windows calculator and perform the same thing on chrome console without any problems (`"123" == "123"` returned `true`)

Comment: @Oriol visible characters maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution for this case:

```
eval("65033‬ == 65033".replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 =-_.]/, ''))
```

You can place your copied text in a string, then remove all unnecessary characters (by explicitly listing the ones that should stay there).

These may include non-alphanumerical characters + hyphen, underscore, equality, space et cetera - actual character that need to stay there will depend on your choice and needs.

Alternatively, you may try to remove all non-printable characters, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598786/how-to-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-javascript).

Finally, evaluate resulting code. Remember this is not necessarily the best idea for production code.

Comment: I guess removing all non-printable chars is whats suits me better, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** after the edit of the original question, this answer no longer offers a bulletproof solution.

```
var myNumber = 'foo123bar';
var realNumber = window.parseInt(myNumber.replace(/\D*/g, ''), 10);
```

What this does?

It replaces all the non-digit characters with empty character and then parses the integer out of numbers left in the string.

Comment: Note: `"foo123bar".replace(/\D*/, '') === "123bar"`. Probably not what's intended. Use `/\D/g` to replace all non-digits.